# Importing a subfolder from a package

Tags: node.js, github, npm

I'm trying to use gtfs-realtime-bindings' node module.

The published module on npm is outdated so I'm downloading directly from github. However, gtfs-realtime-bindings is a super repo has subfolders for a lot of different environments.

How can I specify a subfolder in my require?

Comment: You may also want to be aware that this dependency fails the `npm audit`: https://github.com/google/gtfs-realtime-bindings/pull/35

Comment: Yes, I'll fix that in my fork.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading and extracting the zip file, you can [`npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) the relative path to your dependencies by running it in the root of your project like this:

```
npm i ../gtfs-realtime-bindings/nodejs --save
```

This is assuming that you've extracted the git repository zip adjacent to the project root directory. In your code you can then `require('gtfs-realtime-bindings')` like you would any other dependency installed via `npm`.

Comment: Thank you.  This works.  I was hoping for a solution that would allow me to not have a local copy in my bundle when I deploy into production but I guess there isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you downloading the repo and inserted on your source code? You should be able to use `import` or `require` from anywhere, example.

```
code
__src
____index.js
__gtfs-realtime-bindings
____nodejs
____java
```

You should be able to get the nodejs files from the index.js using

```
import nodejs from "../gtfs-realtime-bindings/nodejs";
```

or

```
const nodejs = require("../gtfs-realtime-bindings/nodejs");
```

Obviously, this depends on what you are trying to get, I don't know that repo, but this should work